# How to get a response from c# MVC controller after succesful jquery file ulpload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I get the response results from the following jQuery fileuplod to set an alert after successful file uploads?

Here is the script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Videos/UploadVideoFile/?isrc=feffwefew",
        autoUpload: true,
        done: function(e, data) {}
      }).on("fileuploadprogressall", function(e, data) {
        var progress;
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $(".progress-wrapper  .progress .progress-bar").css("width", progress + "%");
        $(".progress-wrapper  .progress .progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", progress);
        if (data.success === true) {
          return $scope.setAlert(true, 'alert alert-success', 'Success!', "Video file uploaded");
        }
      });
```

In my MVC controller action I return the following json after the file has been uploaded and saved:
 return Json(new { success = true });

I can see the success = true response beign returned by the server.

However this part of my script seems to execute before I get the response:

```
  if (data.success === true) {
              return $scope.setAlert(true, 'alert alert-success', 'Success!', "Video file uploaded");
            }
```

How can I set an alert from the response sent back from my MVC controler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud use the `fileuploaddone` event.

It will be triggered after your ajax is executed.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#fileupload").fileupload({

            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Videos/UploadVideoFile/?isrc=feffwefew",
            autoUpload: true

      }).on("fileuploadprogressall", function(e, data) {

            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $(".progress-wrapper  .progress .progress-bar").css("width", progress + "%");
            $(".progress-wrapper  .progress .progress-bar").attr("aria-valuenow", progress);

      }).on("fileuploaddone", function(e, data){

            if (data.success === true) {

               return $scope.setAlert(true, 'alert alert-success', 'Success!', "Video file uploaded");

            }
      });
```

[jQuery File Upload Callback Options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#callback-options)